# Simular diferente timezone com Java

Tags: java, java-ee

Desenvolvi uma aplicação web (com java) e nela eu tenho uma regra de negócio o qual necessita salvar o horário de assinatura do usuário. Porém preciso salvar 3 horários: timezone local do usuário, timezone global, e timezone do servidor.

O meu problema é em testar o timezone local do usuário. Alguem sabe como consigo simular um timezone diferente para o browser, para eu simular este teste?

Obs: eu pensei em criar uma máquina virtual, e hospedar minha aplicação nela, e fazer o teste, pois teria somente que alterar o timezone da maquina virtual. Portanto esse processo demandará um bom tempo, quero saber se existe alguma maneira simples.

Comment: Você está utilizando Java 8?

Comment: não, estou utlizando o Java 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você está utilizando java 7 para baixo recomendo a utilização da biblioteca [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) . Segue um exemplo de como localizar o tempo com essa biblioteca.

```
//cria datetime com UTC
DateTime dt = new DateTime("2014-09-15T21:20:14", DateTimeZone.UTC);
DateTime dtLondon = dt.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/London"));
```

O ideal é que todos os DateTime estejam em UTC no banco de dados e que o TimeZone apenas seja convertido na hora de mostrar para o usuário baseado nas informação de local do browser dele. Se por algum motivo você precisa converter no servidor pode utilizar essa implementação que coloquei a cima.

Comment: Boa, vlw. Uma maneira que consegui fazer a simulação do servidor foi setar no tomcat o argument: -Duser.timezone=GMT+13 (eu queria o timezone +13), e deu tudo ok.